# Nested Routing in react-router-dom V5 not working

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

im trying to make a nested routing to my react app using react-router-dom v5 but im stuck!

this is my  Shop component code:

```
import React from "react";
import CollectionsOverview from "../../components/collections-overview/collections-overview.component";
import CollectionPage from "../collection/collection.component";
import {  Link, Route } from "react-router-dom";


const  ShopPage = ({ match }) => {
    console.log(match.path);
    return(
    <div className="shop-page">
        <Link to='/shop/hats'>to Hats</Link>
        <Route exact path={`${match.path}`} component={CollectionsOverview}/>
        <Route path={`${match.path}/hats`} component={CollectionPage}/>
    </div>
);
};




export default ShopPage;
```

the shop component is being rendered by a Route inside App.js
here is the code

```
<Switch>
      <Route  exact path='/' component={HomePage} />
      <Route  exact path='/shop' component={ShopPage} />
      <Route  exact path='/checkout' component={CheckoutPage} />
      <Route  
        exact path='/signin' 
        render={() => 
          this.props.currentUser  ? (
            <Redirect to='/' />
          ) : (
            <SignInAndSignUpPage/>
          )
        } 
      />
    </Switch>
```

and im trying to use  match.path instead of '/shop/hats' in the path but when i go to /shop/hats in the browser it doesnt render anyting.
the weird thing is that the first Route containing CollectionsOverview component is working just fine but the second one isnt.
can you guys help me with that ?

Edit : i madea codesandbox project with the same file structure as my original prooject and managed to reproduice the same issue .
[the codesandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/route-doesnt-work-inside-a-child-rri3s)

Comment: What is the issue, what more precisely isn't working? Any errors? What debugging have you done? Can you update your question to include all relevant code? How is `Shop` component rendered? Is it passed a `match` route prop?

Comment: i've updated the question with more code and description, i hope that would make my issue clear

Comment: I copy/pasted your code into a running [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/nested-routing-in-react-router-dom-v5-not-working-66l3z?file=/src/App.js) is it appears to run without issue. Are there any errors on your end? Try killing/restarting any code watchers/hot-reloaders. If issue persists then try to create a codesandbox demo of your own that reproduces the issue we can inspect and debug live.

Comment: that's the weird thing, wyhen i try it on codesandbox it works just fine. But in my projdct it only excute the first route "<Route exact path={`${match.path}`} component={CollectionsOverview} />" but the second one always gets ignored smh and doesnt render with no errors.

Comment: i've updated the post with a codesandbox link in which i reproduced the issue. hope this help understand it more

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When rendering nested routes you need to allow your root/lower-level `Route` components to match also any sub-routes/paths they may be rendering. The issue here is that you are `exactly` matching routes in `App`, so for example when you navigate to `"/shop/hats"` from `Shop`, the `"/shop"` path no longer exactly matches and `Shop` is unmounted, thus unmounting any nested routes it may have been rendering.

```
<Switch>
  <Route exact path="/" component={HomePage} />
  <Route exact path="/shop" component={ShopPage} />
</Switch>
```

Route paths in RRDv5 work more as "path-prefixes". There is no route allowing for any `"/shop/*" path when using the` exact` prop.

Within the `Switch` component path order and specificity matters. If ordered correctly there is almost no need at all to even use the `exact` prop. Inside `Switch` you should order the paths in decreasing order of specificity, and remove the `exact` prop. This works by allowing the `Switch` to match *more* specific paths first before falling back to *less* specific paths.

```
<Switch>
  <Route path="/shop" component={ShopPage} />
  <Route path="/" component={HomePage} />
</Switch>
```

[image: Edit nested-routing-in-react-router-dom-v5-not-working]

[image]

Comment: nice detailed answer

Comment: worked like a charm mate! thank you for the help, i was really struggeling with this for the past couple of days.